# Not able to limit the digits and doesn't let enter decimal

Tags: angular, regex

Here's my regex: `/^(\d{1,5})(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/` (Digit(1-5 times) . [0-9](0-2 times))

I tested it online and it works as expected.

But when I am trying to implement this in code, it is not working. For example, it does not limit me to 5 digits and doesn't let enter decimal.

Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8mufgm?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

My code:

.ts:

```
validateInput(event) {
    const pattern = /^(\d{1,5})(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/;
    const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

.html:

```
<input type="number" min="0" (keypress)="validateInput($event)" step="0.01" />
```

Comment: You are validating the whole pattern `^(\d{1,5})(\.[0-9]{0,2})?` against a single char `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)`

Comment: okay. Then how should I resolve it?

Comment: I'm surprised you used both `\d` and `[0-9]` considering that they mean the same thing. Also, this matches `"00000.00"` and `"12."`. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes it is okay.

Comment: You could make all the parts optional while typing (assuming the field is empty and that is still valid for the user) https://regex101.com/r/GwMrv8/1 and then when submitting validate the whole pattern. You could also shorten the pattern, but then you would allow typing starting with a dot https://regex101.com/r/L8ZdeX/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird for the response but even using your first regex does not limit the digits to 5 or let me enter decimal. Kindly help on this.

Comment: @Mr.A You should not do the validation against a single inputChar, but against the whole current string in the input field.

Comment: @Mr.A I have adjusted your code below and answered this question, because you said that the regex online test is normal, so I did not adjust it, but if you only want integers and limit the length, you can adjust the regex to /^\d{1, 5}$/, so that only integers are allowed and the length is limited to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only verify the entered value each time.

I didn’t adjust the regex, but I adjusted your code and tested it successfully.

---

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="number" min="0" (keypress)="validateInput($event)" step="0.01" />
```

Replace with

```
<input type="number" min="0" (input)="validateInput($event)" step="0.01" />
```

---

**app.component.ts**

```
...
export class AppComponent  {
  validateInput(event) {
    const pattern = /^(\d{1,5})(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/;
    const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Replace with

```
...
export class AppComponent  {
  previousValue: string
  validateInput(event) {
    const pattern = /^(\d{1,5})(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/;
    const inputChar = event.target.value;
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      event.target.value = this.previousValue;
    }else{
      this.previousValue = inputChar;
    }
  }
}
```